# sklearn - OneHotEncoding and SelectPercintile

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection, one-hot-encoding

in [sklearn example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_column_transformer_mixed_types.html) there is a code

```
numeric_features = ["age", "fare"]
numeric_transformer = Pipeline(
    steps=[("imputer", SimpleImputer(strategy="median")), ("scaler", StandardScaler())]
)

categorical_features = ["embarked", "sex", "pclass"]
categorical_transformer = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        ("encoder", OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore")),
        ("selector", SelectPercentile(chi2, percentile=50)),
    ]
)
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ("num", numeric_transformer, numeric_features),
        ("cat", categorical_transformer, categorical_features),
    ]
)
```

Later on the **preprocessor** is used in **Pipeline** before putting data into LogisticRegression model (as one can see in the link mentioned at the beginning).
In categorical_transformer they use **OneHotEncoder** and then **SelectPercentile**. Imagine a situation: *p_class* is encoded, for example, into *p_class_1*, *p_class_2* and *p_class_3*, *p_class_4* and let's say that *SelectPercentile* removes *p_class_2*, *p_class_3* and *p_class_4*. We are left only with *p_class_1*.
1.Isn't it in a way loss of information that potential model does not see whether an observation is of class 2 or 3 or 4?
2.Could one intepret it as "is p_class_1 or is not p_class_1"?
3.Is such feature selection after OneHotEncoding a good practise?
At this moment, from unexperienced person's point of view, I think that such action can improve learning time, reduce overfitting, but on the other hand the intepretation of the model is a little bit harder.